# Deadlock Graph not showing statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, deadlock, ssms, profiler

I am investigating deadlocks on a SQL-server 2008 (10.0.2531). When I catch a deadlock graph the statement tool tip is always empty. When I export the graph to an xdl-file I see the  statements displayed there. If I open the xdl in SSMS 2008/2012/2014 the statement text is still not shown. Is there a workaround to show the text in the graph (it is a rather complex one)?

Here is the xdl-file (I had to trim the T-sql as the full file is 39000 chars):

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process5826e08">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process5826e08" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:1091901" waittime="2782" ownerId="4875341045" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" XDES="0x2aa723d30" lockMode="S" schedulerid="12" kpid="6616" status="suspended" spid="112" sbid="0" ecid="14" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x401C54D2632D944AB35EA9A0053D52A4 : Step 2)" hostname="BE01S039" hostpid="1880" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875341045" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur" line="3" stmtstart="148" sqlhandle="0x030009006d9f7434f5b94400c4a300000100000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
set     TransporteurID = po.SupplierID
from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail   </frame>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0100090006d6ab284001ae32070000000000000000000000">
exec dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5827b88" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:399122" waittime="2792" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0xb3202990" lockMode="S" schedulerid="12" kpid="1344" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="11" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process581d708" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:403382" waittime="2790" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x4ada7e080" lockMode="S" schedulerid="11" kpid="300" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="15" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail  </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5830988" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:403873" waittime="2790" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x3365cb410" lockMode="S" schedulerid="13" kpid="6272" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="14" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail  </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process584f4c8" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:397517" waittime="2793" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x20f4825c0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="16" kpid="5768" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="13" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder    </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process72b62c8" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:402730" waittime="2790" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x3a6e8b640" lockMode="S" schedulerid="14" kpid="6268" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="10" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5844988" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:398614" waittime="2792" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x2613341f0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="15" kpid="7244" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="9" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5809dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:402735" waittime="2791" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x28ce98450" lockMode="S" schedulerid="9" kpid="4468" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="16" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder    </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail   </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process5813dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="656" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:403415" waittime="2791" ownerId="4875343302" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" XDES="0x980e97410" lockMode="S" schedulerid="10" kpid="984" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="12" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder     </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail   </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process94454c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2811" schedulerid="7" kpid="4292" status="suspended" spid="112" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x401C54D2632D944AB35EA9A0053D52A4 : Step 2)" hostname="BE01S039" hostpid="1880" loginname="UNIVEG\cluadmin-srv" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875341045" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur" line="3" stmtstart="148" sqlhandle="0x030009006d9f7434f5b94400c4a300000100000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
set     TransporteurID = po.SupplierID
from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail     </frame>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0100090006d6ab284001ae32070000000000000000000000">
exec dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
exec dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur    </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process72b6088" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2795" schedulerid="14" kpid="8164" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="9" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
                         </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process943a988" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2809" schedulerid="6" kpid="5040" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.343" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.337" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BE01S246" hostpid="3432" loginname="CAMSQL" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875343302" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder    </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetPODTo300" line="23" stmtstart="1856" stmtend="2866" sqlhandle="0x0300090079ae4f2712fc2b01c6a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
            set     PurchaseOrderDetailStatus = 350
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
                        </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.prPurchaseOrderDetailSetQuantityProduced" line="28" stmtstart="2056" stmtend="2472" sqlhandle="0x03000900c97140116e7ff700afa200000100000000000000">
UPDATE [dbo].[TblPurchaseOrderDetail]
           SET PurchaseOrderDetailSupplierStatus = case when @quantityProduced &gt; 0 then @supplierStatus else 500 end
         WHERE PurchaseOrderDetailID = @purchaseOrderDetailID     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 289436105]    </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process583a508" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2782" schedulerid="14" kpid="7200" status="suspended" spid="112" sbid="0" ecid="9" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" lastbatchcompleted="2015-01-20T15:53:21.123" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x401C54D2632D944AB35EA9A0053D52A4 : Step 2)" hostname="BE01S039" hostpid="1880" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="4875341045" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.TrPurchaseOrderDetail_SetSPO" line="8" stmtstart="280" stmtend="1556" sqlhandle="0x03000900b2d24328674b4300c4a300000000000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrder
            set     PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus = isnull(x.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus, dbo.TblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderSupplierStatus)
            from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrder   </frame>
                    <frame procname="Granny.dbo.pr_purchaseorderdetail_setdefaulttransporteur" line="3" stmtstart="148" sqlhandle="0x030009006d9f7434f5b94400c4a300000100000000000000">
update  dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
set     TransporteurID = po.SupplierID
from    dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail
        inner join
        dbo.TblPurchaseOrder po
        on dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderID = po.PurchaseOrderID
where   TransporteurID is null     </frame>
                    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0100090006d6ab284001ae32070000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
                </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1091901" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock4ebbd4800" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process943a988" mode="IX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5826e08" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="399122" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock9af13f100" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5827b88" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="403382" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock6d96900" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process581d708" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="403873" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock48c5b2600" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5830988" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="397517" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock58fb4ae00" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process584f4c8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="402730" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="locka64d6ff80" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process72b62c8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="398614" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock2ced7e600" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5844988" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="402735" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock9f6bba100" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5809dc8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="403415" dbid="9" objectname="Granny.dbo.TblPurchaseOrderDetail" id="lock9d06e1400" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057595948302336">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process94454c8" mode="UIX"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process5813dc8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <exchangeEvent id="Port801ca800" WaitType="e_waitPortOpen" nodeId="7">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process583a508"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process94454c8"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </exchangeEvent>
            <exchangeEvent id="Pipe4dcdcb680" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="20">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process72b62c8"/>
                    <owner id="process584f4c8"/>
                    <owner id="process5809dc8"/>
                    <owner id="process5813dc8"/>
                    <owner id="process581d708"/>
                    <owner id="process5827b88"/>
                    <owner id="process5830988"/>
                    <owner id="process5844988"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process72b6088"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </exchangeEvent>
            <exchangeEvent id="Port801cab00" WaitType="e_waitPortOpen" nodeId="7">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process72b6088"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process943a988"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </exchangeEvent>
            <exchangeEvent id="Pipe17b39d680" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="20">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process5826e08"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process583a508"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </exchangeEvent>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```